# How to Limit Connections to 1 connect on 5 seconds? (IPTABLES)

Tags: server, iptables, firewall

I lead server in game, which have broken AntyCheat and if there are many connects in one time it break whole server and no one can connect. So the solution for it is limit connections in one time to 1 connect on 5 seconds using IPTables. 
It should looks like:
1 player -> 5 seconds -> 2 player -> 5 seconds (If one connect, it must stop other connects for 5 seconds)

Comment: Is this a busy server? I ask because the default recent module table size, for george's answer below, might need to be increased from 100.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this example answer, the protocol is tcp, and other information has been taken from the comments. Adjust accordingly.

This first example will give an average of 5 seconds between connections only:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -p tcp -m limit --limit 12/minute --dport 12871 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 12871 -j DROP
```

This second example will require exactly 5 seconds between connection attempts, without any other attempt of a NEW connect during that 5 seconds. i.e. an attempt during that 5 seconds will reset the time counter.

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 --protocol tcp --destination-port 12871 -m state --state NEW -m recent --mask 0.0.0.0 --update --hitcount 1 --seconds 5 --name LIMIT_NEW_RATE -j DROP
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 --protocol tcp --destination-port 12871 -m state --state NEW -m recent --mask 0.0.0.0 --set --name LIMIT_NEW_RATE -j ACCEPT
```

You will have to determine where this rule needs to go within your overall iptables rules context.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86224/discussion-on-answer-by-doug-smythies-how-to-limit-connections-to-1-connect-on-5).

Answer (score 1):

Using `connlimit` and `limit` module:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn -i eth0 --dport 12871:12881 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 1 --connlimit-mask 24 -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset    
sudo iptables -A INPUT --dport 12871:12881 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m limit --limit 12/minute --limit-burst 1 -j ACCEPT 
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 12871:12881 -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 12871:12881 -i eth0 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m recent --update --seconds 5 --hitcount 1 -j DROP
```

Then apply new rules:

```
sudo iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4
```

Install persistent iptables package:

```
sudo apt install iptables-persistent
sudo service netfilter-persistent reload
```

Note:

- Change interface name to yours
- Add your port range
- This appends to existing rule, so you may use `-I` to place these rules at the front.

Comment: Im doing it in file root/limit.sh using command "sh limit.sh", is that proper? ipconfig says me eth0, port range for server, that players connects is 12871[port]:12881[queryport] so I think i've did everything good.

Comment: Yes you can run that from a script file.

Comment: So I've tried to connect with another person in same time and did it successfuly. It should let me connect and 2nd player should wait a "cooldown", isn't that rule for one player IP?

Comment: DId you run the last two commands?

Comment: Please run `sudo iptables -L --line-numbers` and post into you question so I can see the rules already there!

Comment: If you actually want any subsequent player to have to wait 5 seconds, then just the connlimit command will do. I thought like George and thought you didn't want another connection from user1 in the next 5 seconds.

Comment: @DougSmythies I see your point a connlimit would be the best here!

Comment: I did run these commands. Im using other firewall script, which is working, so it should works too. @DougSmythies, yeah you Got me. Can you please explain me how it should looks?

Comment: Answer coming using the limit module, not connlimit.

Comment: @DoughSmythies Yes, i know now, but seriously I don't know how rule should looks to make it properly. I'm not familiar with it :D

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen Going to check it, can i add to 2nd line of rule dport?

Comment: yes so they are restricted to those ports.

Comment: "iptables v1.6.0: unknown protocol "--syn" specified"

Comment: Please check you command syntax it should be `-p tcp --syn`

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen Can do connection limit with --seconds 5 --hitcount 1? (1 conn/5seconds)